# I need suggestion how can I achieve this kind of UI in android?

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-seekbar

I want to design `Seekbar` like this:

[image]

Comment: Check this link - https://github.com/warkiz/IndicatorSeekBar

Comment: @Shane this will doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this library https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

i made below view with this library [image]

Comment: I need to positive value as well as negative value too, so where thumb is go that side of seekbar track should highlighted.

Comment: use  `app:dsb_max="50"` `app:dsb_min="-50"` xml attribute for max and min value

Comment: If I do that and give `app:dsb_value="0"` it will draw track to half seekbar